# "of my school" or "at my school"

Tags: prepositions

Which of this is right?

I am part of the swimming team *at* my school **or**
I am part of the swimming team *of* my school

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct but have slightly different meanings.

"I am part of the swimming team of my school" means I am a member of the swim team that belongs to my school. So if your school has a swim team, but it doesn't have a pool, so they meet somewhere else, you could say, "I am part of the swim[ming] team of my school."

"I am part of the swimming team at my school" means I am a member of the swim team that is located at my school. So if your school has a swim team that is located on campus but administered by some outside organization, you could say, "I am part of the swim[ming] team at my school."

In most cases, a swimming team belonging to a school will also be located at a school - in these instances the meaning is equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

In idiomatic American English:

> I'm on the swim team at my school.

"I am part of" sounds fine in a formal or written context, but "swimming team" sounds quite unnatural to me. You could also say:

> I'm on my school's swim team.

"swim team of my school" sounds like an unnecessary unwinding of the possessive.

Comment: Can I say I'm in the swim team at my school.   “I‘m on the swim team" sounds like "I stand on a swim team" to me.  :)   Just curious.. thanks.

Comment: No. In English we always say “on the team.” It’s like serving on a committee. You can be a member of the team, too.

Comment: I just did a little research on this. It seems 'in the swim team' is fine in BrE.

Comment: @dan Sounds like a good news to a non-native English speaker like me.  thanks for your update.

Comment: @mamster thanks for your comments, it is helpful for me. I also found this:[search on this site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8867/is-he-is-on-the-swim-team-correct), maybe different culture in UK.  :D